# combining thousands of list strings in python

Tags: string, list, concatenation, strip, txt

I have a .txt file of "Alice in the Wonderland" and need to strip all the punctuation and make all of the words lower case, so I can find the number of unique words in the file. The `wordlist` referred to below is one list of all the individual words as strings from the book, so `wordlist` looks like this

```
    ["Alice's", 'Adventures', 'in', 'Wonderland', "ALICE'S", 
    'ADVENTURES', 'IN', 'WONDERLAND', 'Lewis', 'Carroll', 'THE', 
    'MILLENNIUM', 'FULCRUM', 'EDITION', '3.0', 'CHAPTER', 'I', 
    'Down', 'the', 'Rabbit-Hole', 'Alice', 'was', 'beginning', 
    'to', 'get', 'very', 'tired', 'of', 'sitting', 'by', 'her', 
    'sister', 'on', 'the', 'bank,'
```

The code i have for the solution so far is

```
from string import punctuation
def wordcount(book):

    for word in wordlist:
        no_punc = word.strip(punctuation)
        lower_case = no_punc.lower()
        newlist = lower_case.split()
        print(newlist)
```

This works for stripping punctuation and making all words lowercase, however the `newlist = lower_case.split()` makes an individual list of every word, so I cannot iterate over one big list to find the number of unique words. The reason I did the `.split()` is so that when iterated over, python does not count ever letter as a word, rather each word is kept intact since it is its own list item. Any ideas on how I can improve this or a more efficient approach? Here is a sample of the output

```
    ['down']
    ['the']
    ['rabbit-hole']
    ['alice']
    ['was']
    ['beginning']
    ['to']
    ['get']
    ['very']
    ['tired']
    ['of']
    ['sitting']
    ['by']
    ['her']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of your code with outputs

```
from string import punctuation

wordlist = "Alice fell down down down!.. down into, the hole."

single_list = []
for word in wordlist.split(" "):
    no_punc = word.strip(punctuation)
    lower_case = no_punc.lower()
    newlist = lower_case.split()
    #print(newlist)
    single_list.append(newlist[0])

print(single_list)
#to get the unique
single_list_unique = set(single_list)
print(single_list_unique)
print(len(single_list_unique))
```

and that produces:

```
['alice', 'fell', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'into', 'the', 'hole']
```

and the unique set:

```
{'fell', 'alice', 'down', 'into', 'the', 'hole'}
```

and the length of the unique:

```
6
```

(This may not be the most efficient approach but it is close to your current code and will suffice for that book of thousands of elements. If this was a backend process serving multiple requests you would optimize it with improvements)

EDIT----------

You may be importing from file using a library that passes in a list, in which case you produce an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`, or you might see the error `IndexError: list index out of range` because of an empty string. In which case you use this modification:

```
from string import punctuation

wordlist2 = ["","Alice fell down down down!.. down into, the hole.", "There was only one hole for Alice to fall down into"]


single_list = []
for wordlist in wordlist2:
    for word in wordlist.split(" "):
        no_punc = word.strip(punctuation)
        lower_case = no_punc.lower()
        newlist = lower_case.split()
        #print(newlist)
        if(len(newlist) > 0):
            single_list.append(newlist[0])

print(single_list)
#to get the unique
single_list_unique = set(single_list)
print(single_list_unique)
print(len(single_list_unique))
```

producing:

```
['alice', 'fell', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'into', 'the', 'hole', 'there', 'was', 'only', 'one', 'hole', 'for', 'alice', 'to', 'fall', 'down', 'into']
{'there', 'fall', 'fell', 'alice', 'for', 'down', 'was', 'into', 'the', 'to', 'only', 'hole', 'one'}
13
```

Comment: One important thing I forgot to mention, in order to handle all of the words individually, they are stored in `wordlist` as one big `list` of individual `strings` so in order to work with `wordlist`, I have to work with it as a `list` object. So running your code @Vass resulted in the error `list has no attribute split` (since `wordlist` is a list)

Comment: @gavmross, made an edit where the data of the text is in a list which fixes that error you mention (I reproduced the error and fixed it)

Comment: Thank you for the edit, however still not working. I edited my question so you can how each words is its own item in the list, so I am still getting `list index out of range` for the `single_list.append(newlist[0])`. I am guessing it has to do with something regarding that `newlist` is updated for every single word, so the last list it is assigned to is ['end'], definitely not sure though. @Vass

Comment: @gavmross, I made a modification to the data `wordlist2 = ["","Alice fell down down down!.. down into, the hole.", "There was only one hole for Alice to fall down into"]
` and it produces the error, so an empty string exists and can be fixed by testing for the length, will update